# Visual Studio targeting arm64

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arm64

I have already develop with an arm phone (htc one), but after I got a p9 lite ,Visual Studio can't recognize it. I enabled the usb debugging, all important drivers are installed. My pc can see my phone, I can browse the files. Adb devices command working and it's displaying my phone correctly, I can see my phone in the Android Device Monitor from Visual Studio too! How can I target my device? Thank you!

Comment: What's your Visual Studio version? If you use Xamarin bits, what is the version number for Xamarin.Android?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 17, with always the latest updates and sdk versions (I'm a bit paranoic about it ). My "targeting list" is full with visual studio emulators, but there isn't any arm64 version, only x86 and arm versions. Thank you for your answer!